# fill an array line by line in a loop

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose I have a loop that creates an array, line by line, starting from an empty array.
Example:

```
import numpy

a = []
for i in range(3):
    line = numpy.array([i, i + 1, i + 2])
    a = numpy.append(a, line)
print(a)
```

This creates an array `a = [0. 1. 2. 1. 2. 3. 2. 3. 4.]`, but I rather want a 3x3 array as:

```
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [1. 2. 3.]
 [2. 3. 4.]]
```

If I use `numpy.vstack` the code does not work when `a=[]`

```
import numpy

a = []
for i in range(3):
    line = numpy.array([i, i + 1, i + 2])
    a = numpy.vstack([a, line]) # Error here
print(a)
```

As a solution I could insert an `if`:

```
import numpy

a = []
for i in range(3):
    line = numpy.array([i, i + 1, i + 2])
    if (len(a) == 0):
        a = numpy.append(a, line)
    else:
        a = numpy.vstack([a, line])
print(a)
```

This seems however rather cumbersome.

Is there a better way to just "add a line to the array a" with a single line that works in all cases?

Comment: Depends on your application, but can you just reshape at the end or are you looking for something where you are using `a` as an array while also appending as you go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wait to the end to convert the list of lists to a numpy array

```
a = []
for i in range(3):
    line = [i, i + 1, i + 2]
    a.append(line)
a = np.array(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy alone:

```
np.tile(np.arange(3), [3,1]) + np.arange(3).reshape((3,1))
```

---

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution using `numpy.vstack`:

```
import numpy

rows = [numpy.array([i, i + 1, i + 2]) for i in range(3)]
matrix = numpy.vstack(rows)
print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to be able to scale this. I would think that you can use `.reshape()` on the array. This also makes it scalable as it allows you to use `-1` in one dimension, after which it [will solve that dimension](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape).

Additionally, I would just append to `a` and convert it to a numpy array afterwards. With that, your code becomes:

```py
import numpy as np

a = []
nrows = 3  # change to increase number of rows
for i in range(nrows):
    a += [i, i+1, i+2]
a = np.array(a).reshape(-1, 3)  # reshape to the format (x, 3)
```